# NSolve an equation and its first derivative

Tags: equation-solving

Consider the following plot:

```
Plot[(22500 + T^2/3) ϕ^2 + 320 ϕ^3 + ϕ^4 /. T -> 96.43650760992945`, {ϕ, -200, 20}]
```

I would like to find the value of $\Phi<0$ and $T>0$ to obtain the first minimum of the above function.

These two values can be obtained with

```
FindRoot[
  {(22500 + T^2/3) ϕ^2 + 320 ϕ^3 + ϕ^4 == 0 , 
   D[(22500 + T^2/3) ϕ^2 + 320 ϕ^3 + ϕ^4, {ϕ, 1}] == 0}, 
  {{ϕ, -200}, {T, 1}}]
```

which yields

> FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.
>   `{ϕ -> -160., T -> 96.4365}`

However, I would like to obtain it with NSolve but it does not work:

```
NSolve[
  {(22500 + T^2/3) ϕ^2 + 320 ϕ^3 + ϕ^4 == 0, 
   D[(22500 + T^2/3) ϕ^2 + 320 ϕ^3 + ϕ^4, {ϕ, 1}] == 0}, 
  {ϕ, T}]
```

which gives

> NSolve::infsolns: Infinite solution set has dimension at least 1. Returning intersection of solutions with -((92291 T)/87992)-(121001 [Phi])/175984 == 1.
>   `{{ϕ -> 0., T -> -0.953419}}`

as a solution, which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eqns = {(22500 + T^2/3) ϕ^2 + 320 ϕ^3 + ϕ^4 == 0,
    D[(22500 + T^2/3) ϕ^2 + 320 ϕ^3 + ϕ^4, ϕ] == 0,
    ϕ < 0, T > 0} // Simplify;
```

Use [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) rather than [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
sol = Solve[eqns, {ϕ, T}, Reals][[1]]

(* {ϕ -> -160, T -> 10 Sqrt[93]} *)
```

Verifying that `sol` satisfies `eqns`

```
And @@ (eqns /. sol)

(* True *)
```

The approximate values are

```
sol // N

(* {ϕ -> -160., T -> 96.4365} *)
```

**EDIT:** To use `NSolve`, use the option `Method->{"UseSlicingHyperplanes" -> False}`

```
soln = NSolve[eqns, {ϕ, T}, Reals, 
   Method -> {"UseSlicingHyperplanes" -> False}][[1]]

(* {ϕ -> -160., T -> 96.4365} *)
```

Comment: Thanks but why is NSolve not working?

Comment: @ketherok There is a dimensional component to the solution set (when phi is 0). It can be removed to get the finite solution set as follows: `In[119]:= poly = (22500 + t^2/3)*phi^2 + 320 phi^3 + phi^4;
NSolve[{poly, D[poly, phi], phi*recip - 1} == 0]

Out[120]= {{phi -> -160., recip -> -0.00625, 
  t -> 96.4365076099}, {phi -> -160., recip -> -0.00625, 
  t -> -96.4365076099}}`

Answer (score 1):

When we use `ContourPlot` we see that min is at roughly `T=0` and $\Phi=-175$

```
    ContourPlot[(22500 + T^2/3) ϕ^2 + 
  320 ϕ^3 + ϕ^4, {T, -100, 100}, {ϕ, -250, 0}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

We then use `NMinimize`

```
NMinimize[{(22500 + T^2/3) ϕ^2 + 320 ϕ^3 + ϕ^4,   0 < T < 100, -250 < ϕ < 0}, {ϕ, T}]
```

> {-8.80964*10^7, {$\Phi$ -> -176.125, T -> 2.97721*10^-11}}

```
Plot3D[(22500 + T^2/3) ϕ^2 + 320 ϕ^3 + ϕ^4, {T, -100, 
  100}, {ϕ, -200, 20}]
```

[image]